# Online Contribution CiviCRM Page Setup in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, contribution-page

Hi All I need assistance.

Im am trying to setup a online contribution page in wordpress and I am following the following instructions as per the documentation[image: Screenshot from CiviCRM Documentation site]

The part that says "**Click on the CiviCRM icon next to Upload / Insert**", the "**CiviCRM Icon**" or the "**Upload/ Insert**", I am unable to locate this part or rather I do not see where it is so ultimately I am unable tp complete this task, or am I looking in the wrong place?? I Have also attached the screen shot of the site??[image: Sample Wordpress Page creation]

Comment: Can you add a bit more info that confirms what you have done - eg creating a contribution page, etc, just to avoid any misunderstandings

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SE. It looks as if you are using the new Block Editor and the documentation only covers the older Classic Editor. I have the WordPress **Classic Editor** plugin installed precisely to allow me to access CiviCRM elements.

Once you see what the code looks like from doing it this way you would be able to work out what you need to put in with the Block Editor. I don't know if there is a better way with the Block Editor, but I don't need to use it.

Comment: Hello Mick, Apologies for the late response.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this really helped, I did not think that the new editor could be the problem, thanks again this really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Jayson
If you just enter the shortcode [civicrm component="contribution" id="N" mode="live" hijack="0"] in your WP page, the contribution page should show up.

When your contribution page is active, you can link people to the page by copying and pasting the following URL:

https://yoursite/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=N

In the 2 above examples, N=the ID of the contribution page that you've set up.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcodes are key to working with modular builders such as the new Wordpress editor. There is an option in the builder to type in text or code. This is where you would add the shortcode which @peterb cited above.